# Efficient way to find unique instances with pre-defined rules (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, unique

I am trying to find all unique elements given a list of instances.

I have had a matching algorithm that determines if two items should treated identical

```
boolean isIdentical(MyItem a, MyItem b) {
//matching algorithm goes here
//return true if a and b are identical with some rules; false otherwise
}
```

What is the most efficient way to find all unique items?

```
List<MyItem> findUniqueItems(List<MyItem> allItems) {
}
```

Due to backward compatibility, I can't use java 8 but will have to find a more iterative way to achieve that.

Comment: Use Stream API of Java 8 : list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()).

Comment: Also, to define logical equality of two instances of the same class - better override equals() method instead of defining your own methods. Then you could use Set, which does not allow duplicates based on the equal method.

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned that I can't use java 8 for backward compatibility reason though, so yeah I would have to use some 'traditional' iterative way to do that. Also the matching algorithm is quite complicated, so it is tricky to override equals and hashcode.

Comment: Can you explain how complicated it is that it doesn't make sense to put the logic in `equals/hashcode`?

Comment: If you can't generate a hash code for your notion of equality, you can't do this efficiently, either.  You've got to either have a hash code or an ordering to do this practically.

Comment: @guiqin Whatever you are doing in `isIdentical` can be done in an override of `equals`. And whatever values you are comparing in `isIdentical` can be hashed. If you cannot see how both of those statements are true, post another Question on that specific topic, with example code analogous to your own. But first search Stack Overflow to see many existing Questions and Answers about implementing overrides of `equals` & `hashCode`. Lastly, in modern Java the revamped `Comparator` class, along with lambdas, can greatly assist. But you said you are stuck with Java versions before Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Given that you are constrained to versions of Java before Java 8…

Override `equals` and `hashCode` on your class, using same logic on both.

Instantiate a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Comparator.html) such as [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Add your objects one at a time, but first ask the set if it already contains that object. If so, you have a duplicate in hand.

## Example

Here is some example code. I think this will run in Java 7, though I am using Java 17 today.

Here we define a class `Employee` with three fields: id (UUID), name (String), and whenHired (LocalDate).

When overriding `equals` and `hashCode`, we use only the `id` field with its [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) value. Study those two methods in this sample code.

```java
package work.basil.comp;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.UUID;

public final class Employee
{
    private final UUID id;
    private final String name;
    private final LocalDate whenHired;

    public Employee ( UUID id , String name , LocalDate whenHired )
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.whenHired = whenHired;
    }

    public UUID id () { return id; }

    public String name () { return name; }

    public LocalDate whenHired () { return whenHired; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj )
    {
        // Match on `id` (UUID) field alone.
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass() ) return false;
        Employee that = ( Employee ) obj;
        return this.id.equals( that.id );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ()
    {
        // Hash `id` (UUID) field alone.
        return this.id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return "Employee[" +
                "id=" + id + ", " +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "whenHired=" + whenHired + ']';
    }

}
```

Make some example data.

```java
Employee alice = new Employee( UUID.fromString( "5228256a-69c5-44d7-8ff5-40703f1b6491" ) , "Alice" , LocalDate.of( 2010 , Month.MARCH , 15 ) );
Employee bob = new Employee( UUID.fromString( "0ee605a2-24bf-4e35-ab68-54007c472717" ) , "Bob" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) );
Employee bobby = new Employee( UUID.fromString( "0ee605a2-24bf-4e35-ab68-54007c472717" ) , "Bobby" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) );
Employee carol = new Employee( UUID.fromString( "4b63c9ef-4921-46ff-a43a-60741bedf9a3" ) , "Carol" , LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.DECEMBER , 1 ) );
List < Employee > inputs = new ArrayList <>();
inputs.add( alice );
inputs.add( bob );
inputs.add( bobby );
inputs.add( carol );
```

Create an empty `Set` in which to put our `Employee` objects. A set by definition forbids duplicates. And we can ask the set if it contains a particular object. The objects’ `equals` method will be invoked to determine the answer to that "contains" query. And in a `HashSet`, the objects’ `hashCode` method will be invoked as part of the store-and-retrieve operations on the set.

```
Set < Employee > employees = new HashSet <>();
```

Loop our inputs (`Employee` objects). For each one, ask if it is already contained in our set. If so, we have a duplicate. If not, add it.

```java
for ( Employee input : inputs )
{
    if ( employees.contains( input ) )
    {
        System.out.println( "duplicate = " + input );
    } else
    {
        employees.add( input );
    }
}
```

When run.

> duplicate = Employee[id=0ee605a2-24bf-4e35-ab68-54007c472717, name=Bobby, whenHired=2021-01-23]

If you do not care which items are duplicates, and just want to discard them, replace that `for` loop with a single line, a call to [`Set#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)):

```java
Set < Employee > employees = new HashSet <>();
employees.addAll( inputs );  // Any duplicates are ignored. A `Set` is distinct by definition.
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
List<MyItem> findUniqueItems(List<MyItem> allItems) {
  List<MyItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
  LinkedHashSet<MyItem> hashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
  for(MyItem m: allItems){
      if (hashSet.add(m)) list.add(m);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Or wrap the hashSet in a LinkedHashList. Of course you have to implement equals and hashCode.

Comment: This only works if OP implements equals/hashcode. And then why not just create the Set from the List directly?